# Showing a Due Date for a budget sheet in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to set up a budget sheet and I can't seem to figure out how to set up a formula to show a due date of a bill monthly.

The bill in question is paid on the first. On the second I want the cell with the due date to update to the first of the next month.

How would I accomplish this?
If possible can you explain the process along with the formula so I can do the same for other due dates?

The extent of my knowledge thus far has been simple math.

The current cell information is this:

D2 should show the date the bill is due.
D3-5 are other bill due dates.
B2-B5 are being used for the amount due.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it seems to fit more other sites from the stackexchange network, like http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: But the question is about excel formula. Will android troubleshooting help with that?

Comment: Then show us what you have tried so far. Be more specific too.

Comment: Is that better? Sorry I wasn't totally sure at first how to ask.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-subtract-dates-b83768f5-f695-4311-98b1-757345f7e926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D3:

```
=EDATE(D2,1)
```

and fill down

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-or-subtract-dates-b83768f5-f695-4311-98b1-757345f7e926

EDIT:  OK I think I get your question now - you wanted something like this

[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually solve my question. Edate only supplies the serial number for the indicate date 1 month after the given date. I would have to manually update that every single month.

Comment: That does look like it'll serve my purpose. It should show the next due date after I've passed the current one. My plan is to do a count of the fridays within that time frame but I can do that on my own. This was beyond my meager abilities lol. Thank you. Can you put it in an text field that is copyable?

Comment: A shorter variation EDATE(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), A2), IF(DAY(TODAY()) >A2, 1,0))